# count and display number of rows based on field data

Tags: database, vb.net, count

I am using a DB and one of the fields in my table is the name of a radio station by call letters.  So i have multiple rows of data and each one has the field with a radio station affiliation.  Some rows have the same radio station (so I might have 3 rows with Station X and 1 row with Station Y).  How do I count the rows from that one table and then display the data with a count for each radio station.  I know I need to loop through somehow but I am new to this.  I am using VB.NET and SQL 2008.

Answer (score 0):

In a table named Station,

```
SELECT DISTINCT Station.Name FROM Station
```

will return a list of distinct station names. You can iterate over this list using a foreach loop, substituting each station name in `<Name>` like this

```
SELECT COUNT(Station.Name) FROM Station WHERE Station.Name = '<Name>'
```

Comment: my sql is as follows:         select 
    COUNT(Station) 
    from tbl_xfinity
    WHERE Station = @Station                       but how do I display it in VB.NET?

Comment: How are you returning your other data from the database?

Comment: this is the only thing I need to return.  It is a page just displaying number of rows per that station.  Station X = 5, Station = 3, etc.

Comment: yes, i have connection set up and am doing database submission on another page.  I can do a count of all rows in the table...I just want to separate based on station.

Comment: I think I understand better after reading through a few times. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstand.  I have 3 stations.  In my DB i have multiple rows associated with each station.  I don't my return to be 3 (for the number of station)...I want it to say Station X has 7, Station Y has 2 and Station Z has 5

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(Station) FROM tbl_xfinity WHERE Station = 'Station X'` will return the number of rows with 'Station X' in the Station column. This doesn't return the number of stations (the reason for the first query was so you don't hard-code 3 station names, to allow for growth if any in the future.)

Comment: yes, but I do not want to hard code 'Station X' in my SQL statement.

Comment: Hence the first query. It returns all possible station names. If you have three, it returns {"Station X", "Station Y", "Station Z"} from SQL. Iterate over them, putting each one in the `Select Count()` statement

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that you've declare the connection and fields name are station and affiliation ..

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter   
dim tbl1 as New DataTable
dim tbl2 as New DataTable

da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM station", connection)
da.Fill(tbl1)

For x As Integer = 0  to tbl1.Rows.Count-1
  da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM affiliation WHERE station ='" & tbl1.Rows(x).Item("name") & "'", connection)
  tbl2=New DataTable
  da.Fill(tbl2)

  if tbl2.Rows.Count > 0 then MsgBox(format(tbl2.Rows.Count))
Next
```